# Is there a way to check if several vars are all equal to each other in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have jQuery included so if it helps to use it, it's available.

**First the simple question:**

Is there a way to check if several vars are all equal to each other?

I can use the transitive relation logic and do

```
if ((a == b) && (b == c)) && (c == d)) ... {
```

to avoid checking every variable against EACH other, but I think there should be a fancier way to do this.

If you can answer this first part only, it would be much appreciated.

**Now, the tricky part...**
I have a variable amount of variables (between 1 and 5)
I know that their value can be any of 200 possible values from a DDBB.

What would be the best way to know how many instances of each value I have within those variables?

For example...

**If I have...**

```
var1 = VALUE_A;
var2 = VALUE_A;
var3 = VALUE_B;
var4 = VALUE_Z;
var5 = VALUE_Z;
```

... i want to get something like:

```
result["VALUE_A"] => 2
result["VALUE_B"] => 1
result["VALUE_Z"] => 2
```

///////////////////////////
**OR if i have...**

```
var1 = VALUE_A;
var2 = VALUE_C;
var3 = VALUE_B;
```

... get:

```
result["VALUE_A"] => 1
result["VALUE_C"] => 1
result["VALUE_B"] => 1
```

///////////////////////////
**OR if i have...**

```
var1 = VALUE_A;
var2 = VALUE_A;
var3 = VALUE_A;
var4 = VALUE_C;
var5 = VALUE_C;
```

... get:

```
result["VALUE_A"] => 3
result["VALUE_C"] => 2
```

///////////////////////////
**OR if i have...**

```
var1 = VALUE_A;
var2 = VALUE_A;
var3 = VALUE_A;
```

... get:

```
result["VALUE_A"] => 3
```

Hope I was clear. Examples were the only way I could think of explaining clearly. 
If this is too complex for Javascript or processing so many possible values up to times 5 can make the browser slow I can do it in PHP and get the result via AJAX but I'd rather not.

Comment: one more thing... the result of this function shouldn't have a zero amount for all the other possible values not present

Comment: See my updated answer.  The GetValues function returns an array.  so, you have all the elements that matched as well as the length.  plus as a bonus they have all my newly implemented methods by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this do?

```
function countOccurrences(arr) {
    var result = {};
    $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
        if (!result[value])
            result[value] = 1;
        else
            result[value]++;
    });
    return result;
}
```

This function accepts an *array* of the values, and returns an object whose keys are the elements and values are the number of occurrences of each.

Comment: This is very basic stuff, and not at all "too complex for Javascript". The `if (result[value]) { ++result[value] } else { result[value] = 1 }` pattern is incredibly common and something you'll wind up using over and over to count occurrences.

Comment: meagar when I said too complex I didn't mean a complex logic but resource consuming. The functions I was thinking on would itinerate all possible values upto 5 times each and while that it's not a huge thing to process, I don't know if in an old computer would do it instantly.

Comment: I'm trying Jeremy's function which makes a lot of sense now that I think of like that. I think this will be the big winner for the question :D

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I don't think there's any special way of doing that.

For the 2nd: I would suggest storing those variables in an array.  So your code becomes :

```
var myVars = [];

myVars[0] = VALUE_A;
myVars[1] = VALUE_A;
myVars[2] = VALUE_B;
myVars[3] = VALUE_Z;
myVars[4] = VALUE_Z;
```

Then you can just simply loop through the array and count the occurrences of each value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create your own object.  The object is basically a wrapper around an array of key/value pairs.  Then you need a couple of methods for .isTrue() or  whatever.

## You said you wanted something fancier....

So why not add to the Array object your own methods and properties to get the job done....  Hopefully, it's clear enough.

```
  KeyValuePair.prototype.value = null;
    KeyValuePair.prototype.key = null;



    function KeyValuePair(key, value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.Equals = Equals;

        function Equals(o) {

            if (this.value == o.value)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }





        Array.prototype.ValuesAreEqual = ValuesAreEqual;
        Array.prototype.GetValues = GetValues;


        function ValuesAreEqual() {
            this.sort();
            for (var i = 0; i <= this.length - 1; i++) {
                var last = this.pop();
                var first = this.shift();
                if (first) {
                    return first.Equals(last);
                }
            }
        }





        function GetValues(value) {
            var arr = new Array();

            if (this.length > 0) {

                for (var i = 0; i <= this.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (this[i].value) {
                    if (this[i].value == value) {
                            arr.push(this[i].value);
                            }
                    }
                }
            }           
            return arr;
        }

    //code below would demonstrate the functionality of the above.
    var x = new Array();

    x.push(new KeyValuePair("A","Hello"));
    x.push(new KeyValuePair("B","Hello"));
    x.push(new KeyValuePair("C","Hello"));

    var y =  x.GetValues("Hello");

    document.writeln(y.length);
    document.writeln('\r\n');
    document.writeln(x.ValuesAreEqual());
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering the first question.

This function might help if there are a lot of variables to compare.

```
function allEq(arr)
{
    var next;
    var curr = arr.pop();
    while (arr.length)
    {
        next = arr.pop();
        if (curr != next)
            return false;

        curr = next;
    }
    return true;
}

var a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1;
var myArr = [a, b, c, d];

if (allEq(myArr)) ... {
```

Comment: If you sort the array first, you only have to compare the first and last element.  Otherwise it will take longer to verify equality as the array length grows.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, that is not possible. JavaScript allows for local variable definitions which can't be lifted from the environment.

The long answer is more nuanced. Variables which are declared without `var` or variables which are declared right on the window often are accessible, but it is a headache to do that. And you can often get a variable's value through eval, but that still does not give access to the variable's name (which is what you need for all of the above).

If you have a series of known values, then you can loop through the variables:

```
var tests = [
    VALUE_A,
    VALUE_B,
    VALUE_A,
    VALUE_C
]

function areAllEqual( arr )
{
   for( var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++ )
   {
      if( arr[ i ] != arr[ i + 1 ] ) return false;
   }
   return true;
}
console.log( areAllEqual( tests ) ) // false;
console.log( areAllEqual( [1,1,1] ) ) // true;

function getOccurances(arr) {
   var result = {};
   for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ )
   {
      if( isNaN( result[ arr[ i ] ] ) ) result[ arr[ i ] ] = 1;
      else result[ arr[ i ] ]++;
   }
    return result;
}
// this is not guaranteed to be in any order.
console.log( getOccurances( tests ) ) // {VALUE_A:2, VALUE_B:1, VALUE_C:1};
```

Comment: In that case there really aren't many options left to you. You'll need to either store everything in an object (in which case they would be iterable) or get PHP to do your lifting.